# Writing to the filesystem in read-only filesystem container running on Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, filesystems, kernel

tldr - I am running on Kubernetes host, and I need execute my agent in filesystem context of read-only containers. (the agent must think it's running in `/` of the container)

I am running on a Kubernetes node, and I need to copy an agent file to all the container running on that node. In case of a read-write filesystem containers it's easy, I just copy my file to `/proc/<pid>/root/tmp/<file>`, and then running my agent using `chroot /proc/pid/root /tmp/agent`. But in case of read-only filesystem I am not able to do so.

I had few ideas (but none of them worked) -

1. Using `/dev` as the destination folder, as it's writable by default. It worked, but the problem is that the containers I was working on had just 64mb available in `/dev`, and it's not enough for me.
2. Create a soft link to the container in `/tmp/<pid>` and copy my file to `/tmp`, this way my agent "thinks" that it's running inside the container (using `chroot /tmp/<pid>`). The problem is that in this scenario `/opt/` and `/tmp` of the container are not accessable and `/tmp/<pid>/opt` is mapped to `/opt`. So this solution also haven't work for me. (Same situation with `mount --bind` instead of `ln -s`)
3. I tried so combine the solutions, and create a mount from `/proc/<pid>/root/dev/my_folder` to `/tmp/my_folder`, but got the `wrong fs type` error. I believe it's because `/dev` is `tmpfs`.
4. using `memfd` to access the files after `chroot /proc/pid/root`, but the problem in this case is that the agent is writing files to the disk - and it will fail in case of `memfd` and read-only filesystem.

so I am looking for ideas, how to solve this problem. I am running on the host, so any manipulation of the environment are possible.

I have the following ideas but I am unsure how to implement them -

1. increase `/dev` using hard-disk capacity, not ram.
2. mount additional "hard-disk" (write-read with my files) to the container during runtime.
3. mount somehow a folder from the host to container's `/dev`
4. changing the container's filesystem permissions on runtime

I would appreciate any help with the ideas I mentioned, and of course I would like to hear more ideas to try.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using an init container to copy the agent file to a new volume (call it newVolume) and then mount that volume in the main container.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: agent-volume
    newVolume: {}
  initContainers:
  - name: init-agent
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp /path/to/agent /agent-volume/']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: agent-volume
      mountPath: /agent-volume
  containers:
  - name: main-container
    image: your-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: agent-volume
      mountPath: /path/in/container
```

Here, main container mounts the agent-volume at a specified path, allowing it to access the agent file even if its file system is read-only. Of course, I didn't test it.

Comment: I need to be able to do so during runtime, when the container is already running. Is it possible to modify this configuration during runtime without restart the container?